# -moz-column-fill: auto breaks CSS columns in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, responsive-design

I am trying to divide my design into three columns. In Chrome it is working perfectly, but in Firefox it is showing only one column instead of three.

```css
body > div {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  -webkit-column-fill: auto;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 15px;
  column-fill: auto;
}
body > div > div {
  background: #F00;
  height: 400px;
}
body > div > div:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #FF0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

Either remove the whole `-moz-column-fill: auto` rule, or change it to `-moz-column-fill: balance` ([The default initial value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-fill))

```css
body > div {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 10px;
  /*-moz-column-fill: auto;*/
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
  -webkit-column-fill: auto;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 15px;
  column-fill: auto;
}
body > div > div {
  background: #F00;
  height: 400px;
}
body > div > div:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #FF0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

That being said, `column-fill` is still only a [Candidate Recommendation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-fill#Specifications), so expect browser behaviour to change.