# FireFox 3 column css3 layout doesn't work, works in Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, css, firefox, multiple-columns

I'm working with the latest browser versions as of this writing. I'm trying to create a 3 columns layout using the CSS `column` property.

It seems to work fine everywhere except FF.

Here is my code:

```css
.row {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 5px;
  -webkit-column-fill: auto;
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-gap: 5px;
  -moz-column-fill: auto;
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 5px;
  column-fill: auto;
}
.item {
  background: #F00;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

I'm also getting these CSS errors logged in FF.

> Unknown property 'columns'.  Declaration dropped. 63f26845e7f429a90b8ae649031e4a073ade7260.css:10876
>   Unknown property 'column-count'.  Declaration dropped. 63f26845e7f429a90b8ae649031e4a073ade7260.css:10877
>   Unknown property 'column-gap'.  Declaration dropped. 63f26845e7f429a90b8ae649031e4a073ade7260.css:10878
>   Unknown property 'column-width'.  Declaration dropped. 63f26845e7f429a90b8ae649031e4a073ade7260.css:10879
>   Unknown property 'column-fill'.  Declaration dropped. 63f26845e7f429a90b8ae649031e4a073ade7260.css:10880
>   Unknown property '-moz-column-break-inside'.  Declaration dropped. 63f26845e7f429a90b8ae649031e4a073ade7260.css:10887
>   Unknown property 'column-break-inside'.  Declaration dropped. 63f26845e7f429a90b8ae649031e4a073ade7260.css:10888
>   Unknown property 'columns'.  Declaration dropped. 63f26845e7f429a90b8ae649031e4a073ade7260.css:10912
>   Unknown property 'column-count'.  Declaration dropped. 63f26845e7f429a90b8ae649031e4a073ade7260.css:10913
>   Unknown property 'column-gap'.  Declaration dropped. 63f26845e7f429a90b8ae649031e4a073ade7260.css:10914
>   Unknown property 'column-fill'.  Declaration dropped. 63f26845e7f429a90b8ae649031e4a073ade7260.css:10915
>   Unknown property 'columns'.  Declaration dropped. 63f26845e7f429a90b8ae649031e4a073ade7260.css:10929
>   Unknown property 'column-count'.  Declaration dropped. 63f26845e7f429a90b8ae649031e4a073ade7260.css:10930
>   Unknown property 'column-gap'.  Declaration dropped. 63f26845e7f429a90b8ae649031e4a073ade7260.css:10931
>   Unknown property 'column-fill'.  Declaration dropped. 63f26845e7f429a90b8ae649031e4a073ade7260.css:10932
>   Unknown property 'columns'.  Declaration dropped. 63f26845e7f429a90b8ae649031e4a073ade7260.css:10948
>   Unknown property 'column-count'.  Declaration dropped. 63f26845e7f429a90b8ae649031e4a073ade7260.css:10949
>   Unknown property 'column-gap'.  Declaration dropped. 63f26845e7f429a90b8ae649031e4a073ade7260.css:10950
>   Unknown property 'column-fill'.  Declaration dropped. 63f26845e7f429a90b8ae649031e4a073ade7260.css:10951
>   mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create meteor.js:532
>   "BookingsController slug " "VBS" router.js:156
>   "BookingsController slug " "VBS" router.js:156
>   "bookingProfile properties" Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object ] profile.js:5
>   Error in parsing value for 'background'.  Declaration dropped. VBS

What's up with this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use:  -moz-column-fill: balanced;
Instead of:  -moz-column-fill: auto;

Thanks to...  [-moz-column-fill: auto breaks CSS columns in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212251/css-moz-tag-doesnt-work-in-mozilla-properly)